# Replace first character of file in folder from Uppercase to Lower case

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, zsh

I'm trying to convert 3,000 or so .svg files from CapitalCase to camelCase.

Current:

```
-Folder
--FileName1
--FileName2
--FileName3
```

Goal:

```
-Folder
--fileName1
--fileName2
--fileName3
```

How can I use terminal to change the casing on the first character with to lowercase?

Currently I've been trying something along these lines: `for f in *.svg; do mv -v "$f" "${f:1}"; done`

All files in the folder start with a letter or number.

Comment: @Gairfowl : I suggest that you turn this into an answer. In particular, the use of the `(L)` modifier could be helpful for other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done very succinctly in `zsh` with `zmv`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -nvQ '(**/)(?)(*.svg)(.)' '$1${(L)2}$3'
```

This will recurse through any number of directory levels, and can handle name collisions and other edge cases.
Some of the pieces:

- `-n`: no execution. With this option, `zmv` will only report what changes it would make. It's a dry run that can be used to test out the patterns.
  **Remove the `-n` when you're ready to actually change the names.**
- `-v`: verbose.
- `-Q`: qualifiers. Indicates that the source pattern has a glob qualifier (in our case `(.)`).
- `'(**/)(?)(*.svg)(.)'`: source pattern. This is simply a regular `zsh` glob pattern, divided into groups with parentheses. The underlying pattern is `**/?*.svg(.)`. The pieces:

  - `(**/)`: directories and subdirectories. This will match any number of directory levels (to only affect the current directory, see below).
  - `(?)`: matches a single character at the start of the file name. We'll convert this to lowercase later.
  - `(*.svg)`: matches the rest of the file name.
  - `(.)`: regular files only. This is a `zsh` glob qualifier; `zmv` recognizes it as a qualifier instead of a grouping because of the `-Q` option. The `.` qualifier limits the matching to regular files so that we don't try to rename directories.
- `'$1${(L)2}$3'`: destination pattern.  Each of the groupings in the source pattern is referenced in order with $1, $2, etc.

  - `$1`: the directory. This could contain multiple levels.
  - `${(L)2}`: The first letter in the file name, converted to lowercase.  This uses the `L` parameter expansion flag to change the case.
    The `l` expansion modifier will also work: `$2:l`.
    The conversion can handle non-ASCII characters, e.g. `Éxito` would
    become `éxito`.
  - `$3`: the rest of the file name, including the extension.

---

**Variations**

This will only change files in the current directory:

```
zmv -nv '(?)(*.svg)' '$1:l$2'
```

The source pattern in the following version will only match files that start with an uppercase letter. Since the `zmv` utility won't rename files if the source and destination match, this isn't strictly necessary, but it will be slightly more efficient:

```
zmv -nvQ '(**/)([[:upper:]])(*.svg)(.)' '$1${(L)2}$3'
```

---

**More information**

- `zmv` documentation:
  https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv
- `zsh` parameter expansion flags:
  https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags
- Page with some `zsh` notes, including a bunch of `zmv` examples:
  https://grml.org/zsh/zsh-lovers.html

Comment: Thank you so much man. But please make it very obvious in the answer, like use mega header title to highlight the part that says "remove n when you're ready to make the changes". I kept running it with that parameter and I didn't know why it seemed to work in the output, but the names stayed the same in the actual folders :))

Answer (score 2):

Solving in bash, tested and working fine, be careful though with your files you working on.

Renaming files in current directory where this script is (1st arg then'd be `.`) or provide a path, it's do lower-casing of the first letter, if it was uppercase, and yet nothing if it was a number, **argument must be provided**:

```
# 1 argument - folder name
# 2 argument - file extension (.txt, .svg, etc.)
for filename in $(ls "$1" | grep "$2")
do
  firstChar=${filename:0:1}
  restChars=${filename:1}
  if [[ "$firstChar" =~ [A-Z] ]] && ! [[ "$firstChar" =~ [a-z] ]]; then
    toLowerFirstChar=$(echo $firstChar | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
    modifiedFilename="$toLowerFirstChar$restChars"
    mv "$1/$filename" "$1/$modifiedFilename"
  else
    echo "Non-alphabetic or already lowercase"
    # here may do what you want fith files started with numbers in name
  fi
done
```

---

Use: `bash script.sh Folder .txt`

**ATTENTION**: Now here after running script and renaming, names of some files may coincide and there would be a conflict in this case. Can later fix it and update this script.

Comment: However, the OP is not asking for a bash solution .....

Comment: @user1934428 what's the point of a statement, didn't quite get it.

This bash solution works fine for this specific purpose.
The question was: "How can I use terminal to change the casing on the first character with to lowercase?".
And my answer in bash script is also on point, i guess.

Comment: Yes, but the OP wanted to have a solution with either zsh or Applescript. Of course you can also program it in bash or Ruby or whatever, and I don't say that your solution is useless. It just does not answer the concrete question.

Comment: @user1934428, Truly, in the question section there wasn't any mention of preferred scripting shell. But if the point was about those tags, then indeed, i really figured it out just recently…
Somehow i've thought the default shell is the bash there, while firstly was about to write in zsh on my mac)
Just mixed things up.

Comment: You have to look at the tags of the question: They list _applescript_ and _zsh_, but no _bash_.  This means that the OP wants to discuss these languages (only).